# Get Matching MySQL Rows from List?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, select

I've got a list of ID numbers, (ex: 100230, 123890, 342098...). I've also got a table, with one column devoted to ID numbers:

```
thisID | name | dateBirth | State
----------------------------------
192465 | Fred | 94-12-06  |  OR
197586 | Alex | 78-04-26  |  NM
197586 | Alex | 78-04-26  |  CA
178546 | Sam  | 65-12-01  |  NY
112354 | Katy | 89-06-22  |  CO
...
```

I need to return any rows with 'thisID' that matches any of the items in the list I've got. Also, note that sometimes there may be multiple rows with the same ID that match an item in the list... in that case, all matching records should be returned.

I've looked around, and seen some recommendations to use arrays or temporary tables or something, but nothing definitive. How should I do this?

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.I would suggest that you find a development forum (perhaps [quora](http://www.quora.com/Computer-Programming)?) to work out generalities. Then, when/if you have specific coding issues, come back to StackOverflow and we'll be glad to help.

Comment: arrays, temporary tables? that's irrelevant. you're basically asking how to run a `select` query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
select * from [table_name] where thisID in ([your IDs]);
```

It will return all the rows that match the given IDs.

See the [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ee28a/1)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `IN` sql syntax for this, if I understand you correctly.

```
SELECT * FROM tablename 
WHERE thisID IN (100230, 123890, 342098);
```

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you!